# Delete button to delete database table row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to give the users of my website the ability to add, edit and remove questions of a FAQ that's stored on a database. They select the title from a form  and then they can press 'select' (to edit the q&a) or 'delete'. Deleting doesn't work.

The first problem is: when they click delete, it leads them to the 'edit' form instead of deleting the database table row.

The second problem: when I make them click the button, I ask to confirm the delete. Whether they press 'Ok' or 'Cancel' doesn't matter, they are always lead to the 'edit' form.

**The code in the admin panel (index.php):**

```
    if(isset($_POST['actie']) && $_POST['actie'] != "")
    {
        $actie = $_POST['actie'];
        if($actie == "csd_faq") { verwerk_csd_faq($DB); }
        if($actie == "csd_faq_edit") { verwerk_edit_csd_faq($DB); }
    }

    if($GLOBALS['logged_in'] && isset($_GET['actie']) && $_GET['actie'] != "")
    {
        $actie = $_GET['actie'];

        if($actie == "csd_faq") { toon_csd_faq($DB); }
        if($actie == "csd_faq_edit") { edit_csd_faq($DB); }
     }
```

**The code for the functions:**

```
//ADD FAQ

    function toon_csd_faq($DB)
    {?>
    <h2>Een FAQ toevoegen:</h2>
    Gebruik het formulier hieronder om een FAQ toe te voegen.

    <br /><br />
    <form action='index.php?actie=csd_faq' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='actie' value='csd_faq' />
        <input type='hidden' name='naam' value='<? echo $GLOBALS['nickname']; ?>' />
        Vraag (Q): <br />
        <input type='text' name='q' size='80' /><br /><br />
        Antwoord (A): <br />
        <textarea name='a' cols='80' rows='10'></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type='submit' value='Toevoegen' />
    </form>
<?}

function verwerk_csd_faq($DB)
{
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $q = clean($_POST['q']);
    $a = clean($_POST['a']);

    $DB->q("INSERT INTO `csd_faq` (`datum`, `naam`, `q`, `a`) VALUES (NOW(), '$naam', '$q', '$a')");

    echo "<b class='roze'>FAQ succesvol toegevoegd!</b>"
        ."<br /><br />";
}

// EDIT FAQ

function edit_csd_faq($DB)
{
    echo "<h2>Een FAQ bewerken:</h2>";

    if(isset($_GET['faq_id'])) //bewerken
    {
        $faq_id = $_GET['faq_id'];
        $faq = $DB->q1("SELECT * FROM `csd_faq` WHERE `faq_id` = '$faq_id'");

        ?>
        Gebruik het formulier hieronder om de FAQ te bewerken
        <br /><br />
        <form action='index.php?actie=csd_faq_edit' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='actie' value='csd_faq_edit' />
            <input type='hidden' name='faq_id' value='<? echo $faq_id; ?>' />
            <input type='hidden' name='naam' value='<? echo $GLOBALS['nickname']; ?>' />
            Vraag (Q): <br />
            <input type='text' name='q' size='80' value='<? echo $faq[3]; ?>' /><br /><br />
            Antwoord (A): <br />
            <textarea name='a' cols='80' rows='10'><? echo $faq[4]; ?></textarea><br /><br />
            <input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' />
        </form>
        <br />
        &laquo; <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Kies een andere FAQ</a>
    <?} 

    else { //selectie box tonen ?>

        Selecteer de te bewerken FAQ.
        <br /><br />
        <form action='index.php' method='get'>
            <input type='hidden' name='actie' value='csd_faq_edit' />
            Titel: <br />
            <select name='faq_id' size='10' style='width:500px;'>
            <?
                $result = $DB->q("SELECT * FROM `csd_faq` ORDER BY `datum` DESC");
                $lijst = "";
                while($faq = $DB->fa($result))
                {
                    $lijst .= "<option value='".$faq[0]."'>".$faq[3]."</option>";
                }
                echo $lijst;
            ?>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <input type='submit' name='selecteer' value='Selecteer' />
            <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Verwijder' onClick='confirm("Zeker dat je deze FAQ wilt verwijderen?")' />
        </form> 
    <?}
}

function verwerk_edit_csd_faq($DB)
{
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $faq_id = $_POST['faq_id'];
        $naam = $_POST['naam'];
        $q = clean($_POST['q']);
        $a = clean($_POST['a']);

        $DB->q("UPDATE `csd_faq` SET `datum` = NOW(), `naam` = '$naam', `q` = '$q', `a` = '$a' WHERE `faq_id` = '$faq_id'");

        echo "<b class='roze'>FAQ succesvol bewerkt!</b>"
            ."<br /><br />";
    }

    else if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

        $faq_id = $_GET['faq_id'];

        $DB->q("DELETE FROM `csd_faq` WHERE `faq_id` = '$faq_id'");
        echo "<b class='roze'>FAQ succesvol verwijderd!</b>"
            ."<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your form seems to use post yet at the bottom you have $_GET

Comment: Don't use $GLOBALS, it will slap back as dragon in the next 12 months. Another advice is not to use one file for everything. Rethinking your structure might result in this question becoming pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check for `$_POST['delete']` and `$_POST['faq_id']`, not `$_GET['delete']` and `$_GET['faq_id']` as the method of the form is `POST`.